# Erro ao tentar rodar react-native run-android

Tags: react, react-native

Estou iniciando agora em React e criei um projeto React Native para estudo. Ao tentar executar com 'react-native run-android' aparace o erro abaixo. Alguém pode me ajudar? Não sei como resolver. Obrigada!

E:\projetos-react\instagram>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
13 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 11 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231 contains a valid JDK installation.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231 contains a valid JDK installation.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (E:\projetos-react\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (E:\projetos-react\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at then.result (E:\projetos-react\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Tente verificar se a variável de ambiente do java "JAVA_HOME" se encontra devidamente configurada, apontando para onde se encontra o jdk

Acabei de ter esse problema e resolve corrigindo essa variável de ambiente.

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar. Obrigada!